# Javascript, innerHTML <option> numeric value changed to string with escape and double quotes

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have a group of options created by a javascript function in a select block. I make the html string then assign it to the innerHTML of of the select block, but (as debug shows) the value of the options gets changed from integer to string with escapes and double quotes and worse, when I try to access the select value in POST I get null.
Does anybody have an idea about what's happening?
Thanks!!!

```js
options = "<option value=64>2. TWO</option>\n"
options = options + "<option value=65>3. Three</option>\n"

document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = options;
```

```html
<?php
if ($_POST['action']=="GO"){
   // I want to use the value here
   echo $_POST['list']
}
?>

<form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" method = "POST" id="userform">
  
<select id = "list"></select><br>
<input type = "submit" name = "action" value = "GO" />

</form>
```

Comment: Your `select` MUST have a `name`-attribute to work. See `id = "list"` vs `name = "action"`

Comment: You need an `ìd` for javascript, and an `name` for posting the data

Comment: OMG @JustOnUnderMillions thank you! I always forget...

Comment: Regarding getting quotes around your values, HTML (or it's rather the HTTP protocol) doesn't differentiate between strings and integers in values. Even if you manually add an integer without quotes as value, it will still be a string when you fetch it in PHP (or any other language). If you need it as an integer in PHP, just cast it as one `$id = (int) $_POST['list']` (after you've added the name `list` to your select, that is).

Comment: So keep that in mind ;-)